# Remove . from file names but not before extension

Tags: tcl

I have a file names e938.564.872.doc and t729.659.5631.xlx, I want to remove their names so it should look like e938564872.doc and t7296595631.xlx etc
I tried 
`set arg [string map {. {}} $arg]` but it removed all dots including .doc as well. can you help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this perhaps?

```
set arg e938.564.872.doc
set rn [file rootname $arg]
set ex [file extension $arg]
set res [join [split $rn .] {}]$ex
# => e938564872.doc
```

(or:)

```
set res [string map {. {}} $rn]$ex
```

The latter method is significantly faster, too.

Documentation: [file](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm), [join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Comment: I'd use `string map {. ""}` to strip the dots, but otherwise that's the right thing.

Comment: Yes. I thought that since the OP used that method, I might as well show another. But it's worth adding it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

To match all but the last dot with a regex:

```
'\.(?=[^.]*\.)'
```